# Session Troubles - Keep Getting "Can't use function return value in write context"

Tags: php, session-variables

I have seen several other threads with this error and none seem to solve my issue - I am thinking it's something out of the ordinary. My server is using PHP 5.4.20

The error I am getting is: Can't use function return value in write context in /home1/tradeinc/public_html/checklogin.php on line 4

Here is the snippet of code I have isolated the problem down to - I removed literally everything from the file except the following lines and the error persists.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = "test";
$_SESSION('username') = $username;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access `$_SESSION` as an array with `[]` not as a function with `()`.

> $_SESSION['username']

Comment: Ahhh, the wonders of not working on any PHP/programming for months -.-

Thanks. I feel dumb now.

Comment: So please accept this answer so other users can see that this answer solves your problem.